# print the exception with date before the logger initialization

Tags: java, log4j, syslog

I'm having a java application in which log4j is used for logging purpose. While i'm starting an application i am getting an Exception in which i am expecting a logs with some kind of date format.

```
e.g 11-5-2015 04:30:24 IST java.lang.Exception
```

I am getting this Exception before the logger is getting initialized.
Is there any way/tools/flags to print the exception with date before the logger initialization?

Comment: You can always write to `System.err` or `System.out`. The exception is complete with date (11th of May) and time (04:30:24). What is your problem?

Comment: It won't print the date in System.out or System.err. My java application is a jar which exits when i start the application. In that error message i am expecting the logs with date.

Comment: You can run your code with attached debugger and tell the debugger to break when this Exception occurs. Then you will see the stack-trace in the debugger.

Comment: In a production environment i can't run it in debug mode.

Comment: Please be insure that your logger is configured at start of application.